Maven Surfire plugin duplicates retried tests in Test-*.xml
In the current project, skipped and failed tests are retried twice. A test is removed from the test results if it was skipped or failed the first time to avoid duplication.
    public void onFinish(ISuite suite) {
        Map<String, ISuiteResult> passedTests = suite.getResults();
        //remove passed tests from failed tests and skipped tests
        for (ISuiteResult r : passedTests.values()) {
            ITestContext context = r.getTestContext();
            context.getPassedTests().getAllResults().forEach(i -> {
                if (context.getFailedTests().getAllMethods().contains(i.getMethod())) {
                    context.getFailedTests().removeResult(i.getMethod());
                }
                if (context.getSkippedTests().getAllMethods().contains(i.getMethod())) {
                    context.getSkippedTests().removeResult(i.getMethod());
                }
            });
            //remove skipped tests from failed tests
            context.getFailedTests().getAllResults().forEach(i -> {
                log.info("Going to remove test case: " + i.getMethod());
                if (context.getSkippedTests().getAllMethods().contains(i.getMethod())) {
                    context.getSkippedTests().removeResult(i.getMethod());
                    Reporter.log("Skipped tests for suite '" + suite.getName() +
                            "' is:" + context.getSkippedTests().getAllResults().size(), true);
                }
            });
        }
    }

In such a case, TestNG generates the correct test result (1 test, not 2).


But the Maven Surefire plugin still shows 2 tests - one skipped and one failed.

How can I make the Maven Surefire plugin show only the last test execution?
Unfortunately, I need the Maven Surefire plugin results in JUnit format because we need integration with Zephyr, and we use a plugin Zephyr Scale that can only parse JUnit results. After each Jenkins build, a test cycle is created in Zephyr. However, retried tests are marked as skipped, not failed in Zephyr, because Test-*.xml contains both the same test marked as skipped and failed.
Alternatively, how can I publish the TestNG results to Zephyr based on testng-results.xml?

Can you please help edit your question and share the link to a github project which contains a sample which we can use to recreate what you are experiencing? There are a lot unknowns in your question and a sample project will help us know exactly what the problem is.

also versions of all plugins, jdk version etc. are required...
